# Mongoose find substring in array of strings

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Considering the following schema:

```
phone = {
   IMEI: String,
   Number: String 
}

customer = {
   name: String
   phones: [String]
}
```

And the follwing data:

```
$ db.customer.find({});

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a65d865b4957f25fc5e653a"),
    "name": "Greg Wilson",
    "phones": [
        {
            "IMEI": "356938035643809",
            "Number": "+1 718 283 4848"
        },
        {
            "IMEI": "356938035643810",
            "Number": "+1 718 283 4849"
        },
        {
            "IMEI": "356938035643811",
            "Number": "+1 718 283 4850"
        },
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a65d865b4957f25fc5e6575"),
    "name": "Bob Wilson",
    "phones": [
        {
            "IMEI": "356938035612302",
            "Number": "+1 718 111 1111"
        },
        {
            "IMEI": "356938035612303",
            "Number": "+1 718 111 1112"
        },
        {
            "IMEI": "3569380356612304",
            "Number": "+1 718 111 1113"
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to find a customer who has a phone where the number contains a specific substring. This is what I´m trying using mongoose:

```
let textToSearch = '111';
let regex = new RegExp("^" + textToSearch);
let query = {};
let phones = {
     Number: regex
}
query.phones = phones;
Customers.find(query).sort({ name: 1 }).exec();
```

Mongoose is returning no data.

What is the correct way to search for phone numbers that contains a specific substring (`'111'` in the example)?

Comment: Try `Customers.find({"phones.Number':regex}).sort({ name: 1 }).exec();`

Comment: Nope, nothing returned...

Comment: @Mendes The `^` indicates the start of a string but I think you want to match on anything (not only the beginning). What happens if you remove `"^"` and simply use `new RegExp(textToSearch);`?

Comment: Good point about the `^` ! But removing is not working. Strange, I can´t make it work.... Check my new try on code edit.

Comment: `phones:{ Number: regex}` will not work. You have to use dot notation. Something like `{"phones.Number": regex}` for query.

Comment: @Veeram it is working now. You can post this as answer so that I can accept. Thanks for helping.